# If two divs have a class added. All the classes have to remove

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have a little problem with my code. If I click 2 divs they show a random Number, but if I click a third div. All my numbers have to remove but it isn't working. Can someone help me?

```
let mijnDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div")
let i = 0
while (i<mijnDivs.length) {
  mijnDivs[i].addEventListener("click", toevoegen)
  i++
}
function toevoegen(event) {
  console.log("het werkt")
  let nummer = randomNumber(1,9)
  this.innerHTML = nummer
  this.classList.toggle("zichtbaar")
  if (this.classList.contains("zichtbaar").length === 2) {
    console.log("yay")
  }
}
function randomNumber (min, max) {
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max);
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

@julie, if I understand correctly, when clicking on the same div, for the first two times it should show random numbers. For the third time, it should clear it. If my understanding is correct, then the issue is that `classList.toggle` does not keep adding classes. If it is existing, it removes it and if it is not there, it adds it. There can never be a situation where `this.classList.contains("zichtbaar").length` be greater than 1.

The solution might be to store the number of clicks in a data attribute and check it to see if you need to generate random number or clear it. MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes